# Angular factory routeParam variable not changing

Tags: angularjs

```
angular.module('app')
  .factory('Answers', function ($resource, $routeParams, $location) {
    return $resource('api/answers?questionid=' + $routeParams.questionId, {
      answerId: '@_id'
    }, {
      update: {
        method: 'PUT'
      }
    });
  });

$scope.findAnswers = function() {
  Answers.query(function(answers) {
    $scope.answers = answers;
  });
};
```

It seems like the `$routeParams` variable isn't being updated as I navigate around my app through different routes.  Is this the case w/ services?  I'm guessing I should define the variable in my controller and then pass it into my service?

EDIT:

```
angular.module('intquestApp')
  .factory('Answers', function ($resource, $routeParams, $location) {
    return {
        get: function(questionId) {

          return $resource('api/answers?questionid=' + questionId, {
            update: {
              method: 'PUT'
            }
          });
        }
    };
  });

  Answers.get($routeParams.questionId, function(answers) {
    console.log(answers);
    $scope.answers = answers;
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe the approach is to inject `$routeParams` into your Controller instead and pass the value to the service.

See here: [Use $routeParams in service](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21938163/use-routeparams-in-service)

so inside your Controller:

```
Answers.get(passRouteParamValueHere, function(answers) {
  $scope.answers = answers;
});
```

**EDIT**

Why do you have `update` within `get`? Here's something you could try but haven't tested it:

```
.factory('Answers',['$resource', function ($resource) {
  return $resource('/api/answers/?questionid=' + questionId, {}, {
    get: { method: 'GET'}
  });
}])
```

but I prefer this approach:

```
.factory('Answers',['$resource', function ($resource) {
  return $resource('/api/answers/:qid', {}, {
    get: { method: 'GET'}
  });
}])
```

and then:

```
Answers.get({qid: questionIDFromRouteParam}, function(answers) {
  $scope.answers = answers;
});
```

Just a little cleaner

Comment: Edited my question to what I have now... nothing is returning.  Is something syntactically off?

Comment: It is being passed.  Look again, jsut forgot to take it out of service header.