# AngularJS Store $routeParam in var in factory service

Tags: javascript, angularjs, url, routes, config

I'm new to Angular and i'm currently trying to get the id of a project from the url and pass it as a var inside a service.

My current code is as follows:

```
app.config(
  ['$routeProvider',
    function($routeProvider) {
      ...
      $routeProvider.when('/project/:ProjectId', {
        templateUrl: 'project.html',
        controller: 'ProjectController',
        activePage: 'Portfolio'
      });
      ...
    }
  ])

...

.controller('ProjectController', function($scope, ProjectFactory) {
  $scope.content = ProjectFactory.async();
})

...

.factory('ProjectFactory', function($http) {

  var factoryProject = {
    async: function(page) {
      var projectID = 'XXXXXX';
      var apiKey = 'XXXXXX';
      var url = 'http://behance.net/v2/projects/' + projectId + '?api_key=' + 
                 apiKey + '&callback=JSON_CALLBACK';
      var promise = $http.jsonp(url).error(function(response, status) {
        alert(status);
      }).success(function(response, status) {
        console.log(response.project);
      }).then(function(response, status) {
        return response.data;
      });
      return promise;
    }
  };

  return factoryProject;
});
```

I know i'm missing something, how can i store :ProjectId, from $routeProvider, in the variable projectID?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A couple things missing here to get this to work. The first is in your 'ProjectController', you need to inject the $routeParams variable making the controller definition

```
.controller('ProjectController', function($scope, ProjectFactory, $routeParams) {
    $scope.content = ProjectFactory.async();
})
```

Now you can access ProjectId in the $routeParams object

```
var pid = $routeParams.ProjectId
```

Now you can pass the pid as a param into the factory

```
ProjectFactory.async(pid)
```

I haven't tested this yet, but I think that's all you're missing.

Answer (score 1):

You need to inject the $routParams service into your factory and access it like so:

```
var projectId = $routeParams.ProjectId;
```

Answer (score 1):

Inject `$routeParams` object to the controller, and use $routeParams.ProjectId

More info here: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngRoute/service/$route

Comment: this question suggests otherwise, because the controller only gets initialised once: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21938163/use-routeparams-in-service